# rails - How to know if dependents exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  with_options dependent: :restrict_with_error do
    has_many :airports
    has_many :owners
    has_many :users
  end


  def deletable?
    [Airport, Owner, User].none? { |m| m.exists?(country_id: self.id) }
  end
end
```

I need a deletable field so that the UI knows whether or not to display a delete button.

Is there a way I can use the callback made with the `dependent: :restirct_with_error`? Or at least get a list of the associations with the dependency restriction?

The `deletable?` method seems redundant since the information about dependents is already expressed above. Also, I'm doing this for multiple models so it would be nice if the code can be shared.

I'm thinking of a hack right now that involves calling destroy then rolling back.

Comment: looks like I can just call `run_callbacks(:destroy)`

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think your code is just fine.

If you still want more generalized approach, you can extend ActiveRecord (modified example from [here](http://manas.com.ar/blog/2012/01/31/how-to-check-if-object-can-be-destroyed-if-it-has-dependent-destroy-associations.html)):

```
module DestroyableRecord
  def can_destroy?
    self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.all? do |assoc|
      assoc.options[:dependent] != :restrict ||
        (assoc.macro == :has_one && self.send(assoc.name).nil?) ||
        (assoc.macro == :has_many && self.send(assoc.name).empty?)
    end
  end
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DestroyrableRecord

  # ...
end

country = Country.firist
country.can_destroy?
```